# Create view from live stats

Tags: php, mysql

I created a sistem to input results from a school basketball tournament. The idea is that after the game the operators will input the result in a format that the system fetches to save in the db in a format like the one below:

Date | Team | Score 1Q | Score 2Q | Score 3Q | Score 4Q | Score OT | Final Score | W | L | Won over Team | Lost to Team | Regular Season? | Finals?

I created a PHP page that calculate many stats from the table above, like Total Wins, Win%, Avg Points, Avg. Points per Quarter, % Turn Around Games when loosing on Half Time or 3Q, % Finals games disputed, Times became champions etc, and many more deep stats.

But I was thinking in creating a View with this information calcalated on the DB and in real time, instead of having the script handles it.

But how can I turn the selects needed from the first table into a working second table with all calculations done whenever we make the selection?

Thanks

Comment: Show your table format `show create table {tablename}` edited into the question with formatting applied. You current script could help quantify what results you need so please include that too.

Comment: You appear to be confusing issues of data storage and retrieval with those of data display. A database table is not a spreadsheet. Consider revising your schema.

Comment: I know it is not. On the other hand from what I understand the application is not the best place to make all these. I see people downvoting the answer below about views.What could be a better approach then?

Answer (score -1):

@decio, I think your idea about creating a view to calculate those stats is not a bad idea. You might be able to do so with the something similar to the following SQL script:

```sql
CREATE VIEW result_stats_view AS SELECT SUM(W) as total_wins, SUM(L) as total_losses FROM precalculate_stats_table_name;
```

This shows the total wins and losses for the season, but you probably get the idea.  Check out MySQL aggregate functions (like average, sum, etc.) here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html

Once you have your calculations added to the view then you can simply do query like this to get your calculated data:

```sql
SELECT * from result_stats_view
```

Comment: Thanks, will try this. Some of the stats columns i want to use ar actually calculations over other columns that will be calculated on the view, so I would be doing a calculation not over the raw data, but over what the view's previous columns were already calculating.
For example the "%Turn around games when loosing on Half Time". I imagine i need to calculate first how many hames the team was loosing the half time, then take calculate how many of those games they won and only then calculate the percentage. Will I be able to do this in the way you described as well?

Comment: @decio I believe that would work.   You might be able to have more than one view that can keep track of separate calculations.  Then you would only need to do a simple query to whichever view you need at the time you need those stats, as long as your original table that stores the stats that the game operators are adding to is up to date at half time (based on your example given).

Comment: @decio So if I understand what you are doing, the users (game operators) are going to go to a page you created in PHP and enter the data into the fields you need to track for the game there?  Then after the data is entered and saved to the database table(s), that is when you want to perform the calculations?

Comment: Thanks @finiteloop. Yes. When I mean real time it is because games are being played as people will be accessing the stats page on the website, so games that have just finished would have stats for the team and players updated. But it does not need to follow the stats of the specific game in real time.

Comment: Also, I am working on this as a side project so only will be able to test this maybe this weekend. But will comeback here with results.

Comment: @decio just was wondering if you had worked out a solution for this?